# How to make checkbox or combobox readonly in JavaFX

Tags: javafx-2, readonly

How to make checkbox/combobox readonly in javaFX but not disabled.

I tried consuming `onAction` event but it didn't work.

```
checkBox.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        event.consume();
    }
});
```

Consuming all events like in code below works but I don't think it's a good solution:

```
checkBox.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
        event.consume();
    }
});
checkBox.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEventevent) {
        event.consume();
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the difference between readonly and disabled ?

Comment: the differance is the visual, READONLY and NORMAL have the same visual

Comment: What is the need to make control read only? Control is for control, not for indication

Comment: so why TextField has the method setEditable(false),it make the TextField READONLY?
I need a solution, not a reason.

Comment: @AlexanderKirov, this is an important use case for me.  I am deeply invested in a complex view.  Actually, many of them.  Sometimes that view is attached to something the user may not change.  I do not want to create a whole new view for indication purposes.  Rather, I want my view to have a read-only mode that I can control at will.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can set the check box to disabled but set the the look of it using CSS.  If you are using the default style you can make the check box look 'normal' by setting full opacity.

```
checkbox.setStyle("-fx-opacity: 1");
```

It is probably a similar deal with the combo box.

Comment: awsome!
so simple but useful :)

Answer (score 3):

You can override method `CheckBox#arm()` with an empty one:

```
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox("hi") {
        @Override
        public void arm() {
            // intentionally do nothing
        }
    };
```

Comment: thanks but I use FXML so overiding CheckBox class is not for me

Comment: you can create a custom ReadOnlyCheckBox and use it in fxml

Answer (score -1):

If you do not want to overwrite the CheckBok class, you can use the selectedProperty.

```
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox("hi");
cb.selectedProperty().addListener(new NCL());



class NCL implements ChangeListener<Boolean> {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean old_val, Boolean new_val) {
            cb.setSelected(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: if the checkbox is selected before the statement must be  `cb.setSelected(false);`. I change to `cb.setSelected(ov);` to handle both cases but it doesn't work in the first time (it can change in the first time and readonly from second times)