# In JavaFX, how to make a whole tree of nodes read-only?

Tags: javafx

In JavaFX, I'd like to provide a read-only view with full support for navigation and copying to the clipboard.

I need the capability to scroll a `ScrollPane` and to switch tabs on a `TabPane`.  I need the capability to make selections so the user can copy.  Because disabling the controls undermines these capabilities, disabling the controls will **not** work for me.

It would be nice if the implementer of the view didn't have to know about this read-only business and I could impose this read-only state upon the view from the outside, by recursively visiting all of its nodes.

`TextInputControl.editable` seems to do exactly what I need.

However, `ComboBoxBase.editable` only prevents the user from typing into the control, not changing the selected value.  (But, there is this: [How to make checkbox or combobox readonly in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15629775/how-to-make-checkbox-or-combobox-readonly-in-javafx), which works for all descendants of`ButtonBase` too.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15629775/how-to-make-checkbox-or-combobox-readonly-in-javafx

Comment: Can you just [disable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setDisable-boolean-) the controls or edit your question to clarify it more if disabling doesn't work for you?